# How to round to some precision in Noe4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, rounding

Currently Round function in neo4j rounds to the nearest integer, but it would be great to be able to do something like the following:

```
round(56.1214740,3) to get 56.121
round(67.3453451,2) to get 67.35
round(3.23454325) to get 3
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is limitation for this in neo4j.

I have done this by:

```
round(10.0^2 * 56.1214740)/10.0^2
round(10.0^3 * 67.3453451)/10.0^3
```

See at : https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1580